# Prostar (Clevo) W670SZQ

Tags: laptop

I am considering a Prostar (Clevo) W670SZQ.

Is it safe to assume that since it only has Intel HD4600 graphics that it will work with Ubuntu 14.04?  Google has not turned up any definite answer.

I am considering purchasing it without an OS. Is there any problem installing it as the primary OS?

[Here is the offer in the online shop.](http://www.pro-star.com/index.php?r=product/configure&model=W670SZQ)

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations like "tu". What is a "tu"? A tutorial? Than write "tutorial".

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! you need to paraphrase your question this is Q&A website about Ubuntu but not about advices on purchasing devices. You should buy the device you consider to be good for you the rest will come. If you need help with formatting the drive (HDD) then please do ask such a question and of course we'll try to help you our best.